# Cant unpack a password protected rar file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rar

I am trying to unpack a password protected rarfile.

```
with rarfile.RarFile(file_path) as rar_file:  # Use rarfile.RarFile instead of unrar.RarFile
    if pw:
        rar_file.setpassword(pw.encode())  # Set the password before calling extractall()
    rar_file.extractall(unpack_dir)

    logger.info(f"Unpacked {filename} to {unpack_dir}")
```

this is the error:

```
2023-07-22 04:01:25,657 - ERROR - An unexpected error occurred while unpacking log.rar: Failed the read enough data: req=231 got=0

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\rarfile.py", line 2197, in read
    raise BadRarFile("Failed the read enough data: req=%d got=%d" % (orig, len(data)))
rarfile.BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data: req=231 got=0
```

**The file isnt corrupted and the password is correct.**

Comment: don't use setpassword but `rar_file.extractall(unpack_dir, pwd=pw)`

Comment: Still the same error. Could it be the fault of the file? It works with other files.

Comment: Do other programs decode the file correctly?

Comment: Yes, I did find a work around though. I will make a reply in a few minutes.

Comment: having a look at [`rarfile`'s repo](https://github.com/markokr/rarfile) it notes that the library supports "RAR3 and RAR5 format archives".  it might be useful to indicate which library version you're using and what format your file is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get the code to work with any library. for everyone else with the same problem I would suggest a workaround: just use os.system and the CMD commands.

Please keep in mind that you have to add winrar to path for this to work!

```
import os
os.system(fr'rar x -pYOURPASSWODHERE "ORIGIN PATH" "PATH TO UNPACK TO")
```

example (the password ist "MyPassword123"):

```
os.system(fr'rar x -pMyPassword123 "C:\Users\User\Downloads\downloaded.rar" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\")
```

Comment: using `os.system` like that looks scary, what happens if your password includes any "special" characters that might terminate the argument (e.g. a space).  you're likely better off using `subprocess.check_call` and passing the arguments as a list of strings